# Count duplicates in an array and return new array with a key value derived from another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, derived

Following on from my previous question, I'd like to change and extend the capability of what was suggested.

Here's the data I've got:

```
const things = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Something',
    categoryId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Another thing',
    categoryId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Yet another thing',
    categoryId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'One more thing',
    categoryId: 4
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'Last thing',
    categoryId: 4
  }
]

const categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Category 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Category 2'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Category 3'
  }
]
```

Previously I've been shown how to do something along these lines:

```
const duplicatesCountWithTitle = (things, categories) => {
  const thingsReduced = things.reduce((hash, { categoryId }) => {
    hash[categoryId] = (hash[categoryId] || 0) + 1
    return hash
  }, {})
}
```

As you'd be able to tell, the problem with this is that it actually returns a new object, and not a new array. Also I'd like to join the `categoryTitle` from the `categories` array with the results of the duplicated count from the `things` array, based on the `categoryId` matching the `id` in `categories`.

```
  // currently the above returns an object in the structure of:
  // {
  //   1: 2,
  //   2: 1,
  //   4: 2
  // }
  // what I'm after is an array like this:
  // [
  //   { 'Category 1': 2 },
  //   { 'Category 2': 1 },
  //   { 'Category 3': 2 }
  // ]
```

Thanks in advance, again.

Comment: Is that desired result just a counter per category?

Comment: @Trace - the desired result is: `[
   { 'Category 1': 2 },
   { 'Category 2': 1 },
   { 'Category 3': 2 }
]` Where the value is the count of the things that match each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
const newArr = categories.map(category => {
    const count = things.filter(thing => thing.categoryId === category.id).length;
    return { [category.title]: count }
});
console.log(newArr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f3x6m12j/

Comment: Thanks @Trace - I've tweaked your code a bit to make it easier to work with: `const newArr = categories.map(category => { const count = things.filter(thing => thing.categoryId === category.id).length; return { title: category.title, value: count } });` as I'm using the `array` in a `v-for` loop in Vue.js.

Comment: Sure, use it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the relation of `id` and `title`.

```js
const
    duplicatesCountWithTitle = (things, categories) => things.reduce((hash, { categoryId }) => {
        hash[categories.get(categoryId)] = (hash[categories.get(categoryId)] || 0) + 1
        return hash;
    }, {}),
    things = [{ id: 1, title: 'Something', categoryId: 1 }, { id: 2, title: 'Another thing', categoryId: 1 }, { id: 3, title: 'Yet another thing', categoryId: 2 }, { id: 4, title: 'One more thing', categoryId: 4 }, { id: 5, title: 'Last thing', categoryId: 4 }],
    categories = [{ id: 1, title: 'Category 1' }, { id: 2, title: 'Category 2' }, { id: 4, title: 'Category 3' }],
    result = duplicatesCountWithTitle(
        things,
        categories.reduce((m, { id, title }) => m.set(id, title), new Map)
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```